# Joomla and simplesaml

Tags: joomla, single-sign-on

I have been researching this issue for a while and didn't get an answer for it. We have successfully implemented simplesaml with open directory (for authentication credentials), Moodle and Google. right now we are stuck in adding Joomla to this single sign on process. I have used: https://github.com/OpenConextApps/OpenConextApps-Joomla to add the login menu item to authenticate to the simplesaml page and it works but after entering the credentials in the simplesaml login page we are being redirected to the Joomla login page. We are using the Joomla access levels to protect the resources after the login.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you are logged in but being redirected to the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this SAML plugin for Joomla:

https://onelogin.zendesk.com/entries/20066026-Configuring-SAML-for-Joomla

This plugin not use simplesamlphp, instead use onelogin php saml toolkit.

Related to your problem, could be a session conflict issue. Try to configure simplesamlphp SP to use memcache as session storage (so never gonna conflicts with joomla session storage).

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-maintenance#section_2

Answer (score 0):

Your extension is probably not implementing/preserving the Joomla `return` parameter during the SSO login flow.

If you can go for a paid extension, take a look at:

https://creativeprogramming.it/it/apps/joomla-extensions/samlogin

it solves your issues as it cares a seamless integration of simpleSAMLphp with any aspect of Joomla (including ACLs rules and a clean handing of the login return URL):

PS. I'm the developer.